# como poner titulo de gráfica highcharts arriba de cada barra

Tags: javascript, highcharts

necesito una pequeña ayuda con lo siguiente:

Tengo la siguiente gráfica:

```js
Highcharts.chart('rendimientosall', {
 colors: ['#00ff6c','#03deec','#f5940a'],
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'RENDIMIENTO'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Acumulado'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['190 cantidad: 6', '240 cantidad: 13', '320 cantidad: 5'],crosshair: true,
  
  labels: { style: { color: 'networking', fontSize:'15px' } }
    },
 
 
 
 
 yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
      format: '{value}',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Rendimiento (Km)',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    }
  }, { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: '',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} ',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
  
  
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'black',
            }
        }
    },legend: {
            align: 'center',
            borderWidth: 0
        },


    series: [{
        name: 'Rendimiento',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: '190',
            y: 112108,
        }, {
            name: '240',
            y: 84289,
        }, {
            name: '320',
            y: 70249,
        }]
    },{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Meta',
  color: 'transparent',
        data: [83712,72341,69638],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
         color: 'red',
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
              let dataLabelText = `<div style="text-align: center;">
              <div>${this.y.toLocaleString()}</div>
              <div>Meta</div>
              </div>`;
              return dataLabelText;
            }
        }
    }],
});
```

```html
<div id="rendimientosall" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:20px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(158,158,158,0.52);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(158,158,158,0.52);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(158,158,158,0.52);"></div>


<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

lo que necesito hacer es colocar el texto en este caso los números que están en el centro de las barras que queden arriba de cada barra para que se pueda entender mejor la gráfica, ya que en este caso el promedio general sobrepasa la meta de color rojo y si se fijan la meta se ve por encima de los promedios que están en el medio entonces no tiene muchas coherencia.

La idea es que los valores que están al centro de cada barra queden arriba de cada barra, estoy utilizando highcharts para realizar la gráfica.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta usar format: '€{point.y:.0f}' en tu datalabels

Comment: Listo ya lo use, pero solo me coloca el símbolo de euro al lado del valor de meta.